# Почему некоторые спрашивающие активны на Stack Overflow на обоих языках?

Tags: обсуждение

Это перевод [вопроса](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/276523/309650), заданного [Andrew Grimm](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/38765/andrew-grimm) на metaSE (а предварительно на [metaSO](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317951/why-are-some-question-askers-active-on-both-english-and-russian-stack-overflows)).

---

Я понимаю, почему отвечающие активны на Stack Overflow на нескольких языка - это даёт больше вопросов, на которые можно ответить.

Но почему люди, которые по большей части задают вопросы, делают это на разных сайтах?

Я могу придумать несколько причин, но не знаю, какие из них применимы:

- Некоторые люди не говорят свободно ни на английском, ни на русском. Они ежедневно выбирают между двумя неидеальными вариантами.
- Некоторые пользователи владеют одновременно русским и английским, и обычно спрашивают на русском. но если у вопроса есть особая ниша, то задают его на английском.
- Люди пытаются спросить на русском, но, не получив ответ, спрашиваню на английском.

Comment: От себя добавлю, что я бы выбросил фразу _"которые по большей части задают вопросы",_ поскольку считаю, что так поступают не только они. И даже скорее не они.

Comment: Не задаю вопросы на двух языках на SO. Владею лучше русским, но для технического гугления по питону например, формирую запрос  интуитивно на английском, такое ощущение что там люди более корректны и льют меньше воды, и контента больше. Если же не нахожу, то ищу на русском, если опять fail - задаю тут вопрос. Видимо когда речь идет о серьезной необходимости люди пытаются написать и туда и сюда. Либо противоположно много свободного времени и установка "мне все должны - пускай все ответят а я выберу", возможно так же повлиял предыдущий опыт когда давали "размытые" ответы на "конкретные" вопросы.

Comment: Я обычно не сижу на enSO, уровень владения английским у меня далеко не тот, я только один раз задавал вопрос - по устройству Magisk. Но есл вопрос очень сложный, вы не смогли нагуглить ответ, а ruSO молчит, то можно и на enSO. По крайней мере, моя позиция такая

Answer (score 23):

Странный вопрос.
Естественно охватить больше аудитории.
Многие параллельно задают вопросы и здесь (на русском) и на других русскоязычных ИТ-проектах, кто, где быстрее ответит.
Всего лишь.
Так как иногда, в решении какого-то вопроса, очень важна оперативность.

Answer (score 10):

А я вот даже языковые настройки поиска поменял на английский язык, на нем просто всегда легче искать ответы. Плюс когда задаешь вопрос на английской версии stackoverflow, то ответы зачастую приходят быстрей, и отвечают люди из разных стран: индусы там всякие и китайцы. Я бы вообще только на английском бы и спрашивал, но к сожалению, уровень языка не тот. Свободно общаться не выходит на нем. Надо ехать туда учиться.

Comment: У меня не получается добавлять комменты на английском сайте, репутация не возрастает. Из -за чего так?

Comment: @IvanVovk, репутация дается за вопросы и ответы, когда за них голосуют другие пользователи, а так же когда ваш ответ отмечают принятым. В Вашем случае - все ваши вопросы/ответы имеют рейтинг 0, а за принятие своего ответа на свой вопрос репутацию не дают, в итоге выходит, что репутация еще ни разу не увеличивалась

Answer (score 5):

Поведаю свой общий алгоритм выбора мест, где можно получить бесплатный ответ на вопрос в сфере информационных технологий.

**Цель**: *прежде всего спрашивающий должен руководствоваться тем, где выйдет наибольшая вероятность получить квалифицированный качественный ответ.*

1. **Самостоятельные попытки решения проблемы**

Перво-наперво обращаюсь к Гуглу. В именно IT-вопросах для меня предпочтительнее к нему, а не Яндексу из-за лучшей поисковой выдачи на языках, отличных от русского. Ищу ответ самостоятельно порядка 30—60 минут: этого обычно достаточно, чтобы собрать необходимые сведения и не получить 100500 минусов за неподготовленный вопрос. Больше тоже не рекомендовал бы ради экономии своего времени: впрочем, после того, как вопрос задан, снова возвращаюсь к проблеме и иногда удаётся разрешить её самостоятельно.

Итак, если самому справиться не удалось:

2. **Критерии выбора сайта для задания вопроса**

> 1) Положительный опыт обращения с ним.
>
> 2) Активное обсуждение продукта (программы, сервиса, языка разметки/программирования, компонента компьютера). При отсутствии таковой высок риск потратить время зря на написание вопроса.
>
> 3) Наличие ответов на аналогичные вопросы.
>
> 4) Как правило, отбираются сайты, на которые переходил из Гугла в ходе попыток найти ответ самостоятельно.
>
> 5) Конструктивные ответы. Просматриваются несколько тредов: если там хамство, ответы вроде «иди погугли» и в таком духе, свидетельствующие о явном нежелании отвечающих выделить две минуты, то это признак того, что лучше уйти куда подальше.

3. **Типы сайтов**

> 1) Блоги и малоактивные форумы — лучше не спрашивать: вероятность получения квалифицированного ответа обычно невелика за исключением случаев, когда действительно виден профессионализм потенциальных отвечающих.
>
> 2) Обращение непосредственно к разработчикам — подходит для относительно небольших продуктов, например, плагинов. Перед заданием вопроса осматриваю, всё ли в порядке с активностью разработчиков (п. 2.2).
>
> 3) Сообщества продуктов — проверяю активность и качество ответов (пп. 2.2, 2.5)
>   4. Общие форумы — для обращения по темам, затрагивающих большое количество пользователей. Обращаю внимание на все критерии пункта 2.

Теперь конкретно о проектах Stack Exchange. мне они приглянулись прежде всего лучшим во всём интернете качеством ответов по многим тематикам. И в первую очередь англоязычная версия, — причинами задавать в русской вижу вышеперечисленные:

> 1) Кросспостинг ради охвата аудитории.
>
> 2) Языковой барьер. Если и там и здесь «большая вероятность получить квалифицированный качественный ответ» (см. цель), сначала вопрос будет задан на родном языке, т. к. он понятнее.
>
> 3) Речь идёт о продуктах, специфичных для русскоязычных пользователей (как  [vkontakte-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte-api)).

Пример, обобщающий сказанное: для не самых сложных вопросов о вёрстке множество специалистов и на этом сайте, тогда как по метке [sublime-text-3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime-text-3) сомневаюсь, чтобы мне также [разжевали механизм создания собственной подсветки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36019245/5951529), как это сделал [разработчик плагинов](http://mattdmo.com/) для Sublime Text.

Comment: проводить исследование целый час прежде чем вопрос задать—это может быть бесполезной тратой времени и может сделать ваш вопрос менее полезным для других (больше—не всегда лучше). Если у вас за 5-10 минут не получилось найти SO ответ в веб-поисковике, то опубликуйте ваш вопрос как вы его понимаете на данный момент и продолжите ваши поиски, возможно обновляя ваш вопрос или даже задавая новый, если ваше понимание задачи улучшилось настолько, что настоящий вопрос сильно отличается от исходного.

Comment: @jfs, у меня итак многовато минусов, а за неподготовленные вопросы, чую, их количество увеличится в разы. Ну и медлительный я, чего греха таить, мне 5—10 минут не хватит. Правда, сейчас, скорее, другими критериями руководствуюсь: *1)* В самостоятельных поисках ответа зашёл в тупик (времени уходит приблизительно полчаса—час), *2)* Если определил, что потенциальный путь разрешения, по всей вероятности, многоступенчатый, то уточняю у других, в правильном ли направлении двигаюсь. // Также не упомянул в данном ответе о сервисах «Вопрос—Ответ». Он требует доработки, если не забуду — поправлю.

Comment: О вероятной распространённости вопроса тоже ничего не сказал: если решение наверняка может понадобиться кому-то кроме тебя, то что-то да должно нагуглиться. Не упомянул и про языки: когда искать сразу на английском, а где начинать с русского.

Answer (score 5):

На английском сайте больше готовых решений. Но на русском легче расспрашивать о подробностях, чтобы разобраться в сути дела.

Answer (score 2):

есть родной и есть английский! Английский, быстрее выше сильнее, это же всетаки первый технический.....ну а свой родной это уже для полноты понимания. потому как иногда хочется понять суть а не просто получить ответ и скопипастить его(что я тут вижу регулярно....все только и ждут готовый кусок кода чтобы скопипастить его и забыть)

надеюсь ответил на ваш вопрос.

з.ы. для себя открыл английскую ветку, там, реально, все уже спрашивали и есть уйма ответов. Каждый в своем прав и верен, хоть и содержит в себе небольшие огрехи :)

Answer (score 1):

Использую по-умолчанию англоязычную версию, но иногда на некоторые вопросы больше вероятности получить ответ в русскоязычном сегменте, например про такие цмс как битрикс или UMI, которые в буржнэте не так популярны.
Eсть специфичность для каждой версии.

Answer (score 0):

Задал [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798823/omnimarkuppreviewer-404) в английский раздел, поскольку по опыту участия в Википедии сомневаюсь, что русскоязычные пользователи юзают плагин, о котором идёт речь в вопросе, да и вообще правят её и прочие вики-сайты через текстовые редакторы, а не веб-интерфейс. Толку, правда, нет — ни одного ответа или комментария. Спасибо.

Comment: вы пользуетесь плагином? значит как минимум один русскоязычный пользователь "юзает плагин", а где один, там и второй. Так на любой вопрос можно сказать "у меня специфичная проблема, сомневаюсь, что русскоязычные пользователи с нею сталкивались, а значит мне здесь не помогут"

Comment: @BOPOH//

> а где один, там и второй. — Из чего это логически должно следовать?// Моё мнение основано на аналогии, что в русском разделе Википедии в отличие от английского, на техническом форуме никогда не обсуждалось редактирование через внешние программы, отсутствует даже перевод [соответствующей страницы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_editor_support). На русском форуме вики в принципе не отвечают на мои техвопросы, гораздо эффективнее задавать их сразу на английский, который читает гораздо больше человек.// Ваше на чём? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Возможно, в данном случае, может иметь место «культурный аспект» – русскоязычные коллеги просто не привыкли делиться знаниями (конкуренция против кооперации). Возможно, русскоязычный форум Википедии был запущен совершенно для другой цели, нежели  ответы на подобные вопросы. В любом случае, отсутствие поддержки не говорит об отсутствие специалистов в языковой нише.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, касательно Русской Википедии отметил бы 3 фактора.//1. Классных программистов набирается не один десяток, но они особо не спешат делиться знаниями. Практически все мануалы приходится читать на английском.//2. ~99 процентов участников РуВики пользуется стандартным функционалом, о котором и ведётся речь на техническом форуме. На техфоруме же АнглоВики о чём только не спрашивают.//3. Сообщество РуВики довольно консервативно: на внесение прогрессивных изменений, если за них не стоят наиболее влиятельные администраторы, могут уходить годы.//Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, нормальные программисты давно поняли, что такое википедия (кто там, по настоящему, правит балом) и плюнув, ушли в лурк или просто ушли.

Answer (score 0):

Просто есть темы, на которые не получить ответ на английском, напр. всё, что касается API для ВК, ОК, итд. 
Всё остальное на много компетентнее отвечается на английском.