# Является ли правильным размещать вопрос на двух StackOverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, перевод-содержимого

Не первый раз задаю один и тот же вопрос на [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) и на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) (по причине того, что вопрос просто остается без ответа).
Вот пример одного из таких вопросов: [ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/859719) и [en](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51501983).

Вопрос в том, насколько правильно я поступаю и является ли это правильным?

Comment: как минимум модератор @Qwertiy так же поступает :-)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276523/309650 & https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2693/178988

Comment: Это настолько правильно, что для этого на сайте даже присутствует [механизм ассоциации вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4500) :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

На 90 процентов правильно. А если правильный ответ перевести и [предложить ассоциацию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4409), то все сто.

Расширю ответ. Для Stack Overflow вопросы и ответы являются жизненно важным ресурсом. Поэтому нет совершенно ничего предосудительного в том, чтобы задавать вопросы на обеих версиях сайта.

Более того, получив полезный ответ на одном из сайтов, можно перевести его и запостить от своего имени на другом. Таким образом, приумножая и распространяя информацию.

Comment: Расширю вопрос. Изменится ли ответ, если добавить в список площадок размещения вопроса нечто чужое, не SO-based?

Comment: @vp_arth, мне кажется что это в первую очередь радикально меняет сам вопрос. В таком случае на первом плане будет стоять свобода выбора личности - где размещать свои вопросы. В оригинальном же вопросе, помимо этого не в меньшей мере присутствует заинтересованность в том, как сообщество и администрация конкретного ресурса (SO) относится к предмету вопроса. С учетом что вопрос задан на мете, скорее всего именно такой интерес и преследовался.